# Absolute positioned image in border radius wrapper

Tags: css

I have a wrapper with border radius. Inside the wrapper I have a absolute positioned image in the top right corner. My problem is that the image doesn't crop/hide under the wrapper with border radius. I've tried overflow:hidden on the wrapper but it doesn't work. See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Image tag is not affected by border-radius.

Your best bet is to use the picture as a background like:

```
<div id="someimage" style="background:url('image.jpg');border-radius: 5px; height: 200px; width: 500px;"></div>
```

The element(in above example a div) should contain the size of the actual image), and unless you use CSS3, the image cannot be resized like `<img>` tag

Comment: this is likely to be the problem, although in fact it is browser-dependant: some browsers do crop foreground images, others don't.

Comment: @Spudley: I think the problem is that curved borders impinge upon the inside of the content box whereas non-curved borders stay completely outside the content box so this problem doesn't arise for them. The content box (and hence the clipping) is still rectangular even when the border is not. Does that make sense or is my thinking confused by fatigue?

Comment: @mu is too short, I dont know about Spudley, but I am confused. :P

Comment: AFAIK, the contents gets drawn inside the content box and the border goes around the content box. A curved corner has to eat into the content box (which is rectangular) a little bit; then, the content which is drawn on top will overwrite the inner part of the curved corner.

Comment: @Spudley, which browser would that be?

Comment: @Starx - it varies between browser versions. Generally, older browsers didn't crop foreground images. I believe Firefox 3.x is the most widely-used browser that doesn't crop them, but FF4 does.

Comment: What does the spec say? Webkit is the only rendering engine I tested that doesn't apply border-radius to content images. (Mozilla and IE9 do.) It seems like all content should respect the border-radius of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate absolutely positioned `<div>` for the border so that you can place the border above your absolutely positioned image. For example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner">
        <img id="i" width="75" height="75" src="http://placekitten.com/75/75">
    </div>
    <div id="border"></div>
</div>
```

And some CSS (WebKit border radius properties only, the rest are left as an exercise for the reader):

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#inner {
    margin: 2px; /* Make room for the border */
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

#border {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And the usual example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6e622/

The `<div id="border">` is certainly a hack (and I feel a bit dirty for coming up with it) but maybe it will work for you.